# Instant sale feature in Metaplex NFTs?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I have an NFT listed in my Metaplex (instant sale). However I want to sell them in my e-commerce site and just take all the necessary information for me to display and proceed the sale there instead in metaplex. I notice in the solana explorer of my NFT, the owner now is not my wallet(which is the 2nd row) and (I think the current owner wallet is generated by metaplex once you listed it via instant sale? I am not sure please let me know). Now I want to create a sendtransaction and basing all info to this wallet address  and with that I need its keypair to sign it off. Basically I want to transfer an NFT from my wallet to other wallet. My question is where do I get the keypair of this metaplex generated wallet(assuming it is from them) so I can proceed with the send transaction or do I miss something in order for the sendtransaction to work?

[image: Solana explorer]

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are using the storefront auction manager mechanism.

Auction manager takes over the ownership of the mint when listing.

It is not possible to get the KeyPair of the auction manager as this is discarded after the creation of the account.

However, your wallet will be the authority on the auction manager, which means that you can end the auction early and reclaim your NFT.

You can do that via your storefront!

Once you have the NFT back, you then send it to your other wallet and then relist from there.

PS. The upcoming Auction House (v2) framework is escrowless, meaning that in the future you will be able to list NFTs while they stay in your wallet. However for now (and if you are using the current v1 Storefront), you temporarily lose ownership of the NFTs while they are in auction.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Now it make sense. But I have one question, If a wallet is made via phantom browser extension. How can I sign a transaction without having the keypair? Sorry If my question but I am new to blockchain and I want to understand things.